# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Unable to complete login process due to delay in prelogin response

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is my SQL Server 2008 R2:
[image]

Every now and then, my sql server is crashing.
When a query is sent to server after it has crashed, this is the error message I get:

```
[08001] : .  [HYT00] : Login timeout expired [08001] : Unable to complete login process due to delay in prelogin response
```

Any idea what this error is about? Also, how can I figure out what is causing the server to crash?

There is not many logs in the windows log viewer:
[image]

Looking at the memory usage / cpu usage, it appears normal also. CPU is at 1% and memory usage is at 97%.

Comment: The only way I have been able to fix this sql server is by rebooting it. This is less than ideal solution. It happened once yesterday also.

Comment: Here are the logs from today (got it from SQL Server Management Studio) http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=FvYjbJDq

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if worker threads are full and the scheduler is not able to allocate any new workers to the login task.